# How does VSCode measure the activation time?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When Navigating to Running Extensions Tab of VSCode, there are extensions and their Activation time displayed.

- What is the difference between Activation & Startup Activation?
- How does VSCode measure the activation time? What is the span of the activation time here?

We have tried to measure the timespan of activate function of the extension, also tried to do calculation with the end time when activate function finishes and the extension host log file time.  The data we collected looks not align with both. So how to make sense of the activation time?